# How to capture MMI code result?

Tags: android

Is it possible to capture MMI result in Android?
I need to do things like put on hold, merge calls, etc. and as the only telephony events in android are NEW_OUTGOING_CALL, RINGING, OFFHOOK and IDLE, I need to get the result when i dial  any MMI code like Held Code.
Is it possible?

The best solution for me would be to find some way to discover when an outgoing call gets actually connected. Maybe has somebody find any workaround for that?
I made some progress in that question reading system logs (LogCat) and searching for determinate strings, but it seems that logs differs between models and SO versions so this is not a consistent aproach.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get it using RIL(Radio Interface Layer)

try something like:

```
1) adb device shell 
2) logcat -b radio
```

Answer (score 0):

// Navigate to the page that you have dial *#06# in dialpad then execute jar below to get the IMEI result

```
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;

import android.util.Log;
public class SIM_Info_Reader_png extends UiAutomatorTestCase{

    public void getPromptedIMEI() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        UiObject list = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("android:id/text1"));
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("IMEI=" + list.getText());

    }
}
```